# Should I mock a $this->doSomething() call in unit testing?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, mockery

I am quite new to the testing world and I am trying to wrap my head around mocking and Mockery. I know how to mock certain classes that are being called. Fortunately Laravel makes that very easy.

Over the time I learned that you divide your methods in, for example, the Controller classes into smaller chunks. So each of those smaller methods does more or less only one thing and that is, as I heard, way better for testing.

Lets assume my Controller class looks like this:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
  public function myMethod($request)
  {
    $this->validateRequest($request);
    $response = App\ModelClass::doSomething();
    return response()->json($response)
  }

  protected function validateRequest($request)
  {
    // do some validation here
  }
}
```

As I understand it, unit tests are used to check the methods in isolation and I should divide the code in as little chunks as possible to make it easier to test them (so one method does only one thing etc)

Is it a good practice to test, in this example, `myMethod` in isolation and check if it calls the other methods? I know this doesn't work but can I mock it similar like this? And should I do it this way?

```
\Mockery::mock('App\Http\Controllers\MyController')
  ->shouldReceive('validateRequest')
  ->once();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly you cannot intercept unpublic methods. This is a part of a unit test, so it should run properly. If you want to intercept part of a logic inside that method you should think about refactoring it to a service class and then you can call it like this:

```
public function myMethod($request)
{
   app(RequestService::class)->validateRequest($request);
   $response = App\ModelClass::doSomething();
   return response()->json($response)
}
```

then you can mock it like:

```
App::shouldReceive('make->validateRequest') (...)
```

Comment: Thanks, that sheds some light into the whole thing =)
I also found some info now that one should usually just not unit-test laravel controllers. they are supposed to be called via http and then executed as a whole. I guess I just have to use functional tests for it and test the controller and the member functions that it calls as a whole. Fortunately I can still mock every service classes like you explained.